# Watch for current value of input with update on blur

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jqlite

I have following input and it updates model on blur event.

```
<input
  es-max-type
  class="headline"
  ng-change="edit(selectedRow, '{{selectedRow.name}}');"
  ng-model="selectedRow.name"
  ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"/>
```

es-max-type directive is watching for string length.

```
scope.$watch(function() {
    return scope.ngModel
}, function(text) {
    if(text) {
        scope.currentLen = text.length;
    }
});
```

Whenever input is focused I'm showing in corner "15/100" number of characters. But since model is updated only on blur event, I'm unable to track changes during editing. Is there a way to get string length without removing update on blur?

Comment: Try ng-keydown (https://github.com/j-ulrich/jquery-simulate-ext) and do not use the watcher. It is not good for performance.

Comment: So how I can get string length using ng-keydown? I can't count characters since user can delete symbol... Should I track the 'delete' keys also?

Comment: Look at the docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeypress there is an example there.

Comment: try to delete few characters, it doesn't track length

Answer (score 0):

Try to listen "input" event. And not "change" or "blur"